# How to add a vertical botton with top to bottom text in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I wanted to ask if it is possible to make a vertical button in which the text is written top to down? For instance, consider the basic button when dropped into the layout. I want to rotate it and make the "button" text written vertically.

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: [I meant a button like this](https://www.talkgraphics.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=61241&d=1242981451)

Comment: Did you try setting [android:rotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:rotation)?

Comment: @0X0nosugar May I ask you to illustrate its implementation? Would the text be top-to-down after the rotation? Thanks. (Sorry for being a newbie)

Comment: Do you want the characters to be straight, or rotated as well?

Comment: Had you tryed as like: ```android:text="b\nu\nt\nt\nt\no\n\na\nc\nt\ni\o\nn"``` ?

Comment: I added an example after editing the post @SusmitAgrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its text like this `android:text="B\nu\nt\nt\no\nn"`. Don't use `rotation`. Change its width to what you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height to wrap_content and width to around 30dp.

```
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Or use rotation attribute to 90.

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't that just rotate the button? What happens to the text if you say wrap_content to height?

Comment: Provide some example so we can understand better.

Comment: What I mean is, I want the default button to be vertical, (or rotated 90 degrees) but then you would have to rotate your head to read the text in the button. So I would like to have a top-to-bottom style text after rotating the button. I hope my explanation is intuitive

Comment: So the 1st option does that only, did you try that?

Comment: I meant a button like this. Check the button's text, https://www.talkgraphics.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=61241&d=1242981451

Comment: Yes, the fist option does that only. You'll also have to style it of course.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yours works when I edit the text by adding "\n"s in the text. Just like mTak mentioned in his answer.

Comment: If we set width to fit just one text(30 dp for my case) and height to wrap it works fine without using "\n" .